# Select DIV out of all DIVs with Same class if display block

Tags: jquery

I have a following Div Structure, with same class names. I want to only select the DIV, which has display:block:-

```
<div class="popup popup-video" id="xyz_id" style="display: block; position: fixed; opacity: 1; z-index: 11000; left: 50%; margin-left: -275px; top: 50%; margin-top: -173px;">
   <h2 class="popup-title">XYZ</h2>    
</div>

 <div class="popup popup-video" id="abc_id">
    <h2 class="popup-title">ABC</h2>
 </div>

 <div class="popup popup-video" id="abc_id">
    <h2 class="popup-title">ABC</h2>
 </div>

<div class="popup popup-video" id="xyze_id" style="display: none; position: fixed; opacity: 1; z-index: 11000; left: 50%; margin-left: -275px; top: 50%; margin-top: -173px;">
    <h2 class="popup-title">XYZE</h2>    
</div>
```

Is it possible in JQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Thanks Mike.

This is what I did.

```
$("div.popup-video").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("display") === "block";
}).each(function () {
   alert($("#"+this.id).find(".jwplayer-video").children().children().attr("id"));
});
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div.popup-video").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("display") === "block";
});
```

To get the first div within this div, try something like this:

```
$("div.popup-video").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("display") === "block";
}).find("div:first");
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, could you elaborate a little. In the function you mentioned, I'd get the id="xyz_id". What I wanna do is, that I want to access the first DIV inside the <DIV> with id=xyz_id. Thanks!

Comment: Look at my answer. It may be helpful to look through the jQuery documentation to understand what I am doing: [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/), [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/).